# WooCommerce find_matching_product_variation() - how to prioritize variation when there are few of them?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

So I am finding a variation by matching attributes with this function:

```
function rdk_find_variation($product_id, $attributes) {
    $product_data_store = new WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT();
    $product = new WC_Product($product_id);

    return $product_data_store->find_matching_product_variation($product, $attributes);
}
```

But, if there are, for example, two variation that matches the attributes, like:

- Variation 1: color: yellow, size: XL
- Variation 2: color: any, size: any

This function will simply return the first variation that its found - the one with the lower ID.

I need variations with attribute values: `Any` to be prioritized over variation with specific attribute value - just like the WooCommerce single product page behaves when user is selecting attribute values before adding product to cart.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function from `WC_Product_Variable` class called `get_available_variations()` that will return the product variation data. You can access it by calling it on the product object. It returns an array of data for each variation. The sort order is matching the front end sort order.

```
function rdk_get_variations($product_id) {
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
  $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
  return $variations;
}

// To access each id from the array
$variations = rdk_get_variations($product_id);
foreach ($variations as $var) {
  echo $var['variation_id'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that but I can't figure out how I can use that to get  the variation id by matching attributes.

Comment: The id is in the `variation_id` field. You can access it by looping through the array.

Comment: I understand that, but I would need to write a code which would prioritize (during attribute values comparation) variations with 3 `any` values over variations with 2 `any` values, and 2 `any` over 1 `any`, and finally 1 `any` over defined attribute value, which would take too much time and I am not sure if I can find an elegant way to do.

Comment: I interpreted your question to mean the function was returning the variations ordered by ID, not the order you'd set on the product. There's also a function for the default variation, which I think is what you're referring to. Otherwise you could sort an array of the values, or try WP_Query.